# How to set "z-index" of an element in Apache Royale (equivalent of setElementIndex in Flex)?

Tags: image, z-index, apache-royale

I want to make a simple pictures slideshow with Apache Royale.
To simplify I have 2 `<j:Image>` in a `<j:Group>`. Something like this (but written dynamicaly in as3)

```
<j:Group>
    <j:Image src="1.jpg" id="im1"/>
    <j:Image src="2.jpg" id="im2"/>
</j:Group>
```

This would result of 2.jpg visible because im2 is after im1.  Now I want to set position of im2 before im1. This would be the equivalent of **setElementIndex** of Flex. (I don't want to play with **visible**)

Is it possible ? How to do ?

Regards

Comment: More of a general comment: if what you're after is porting a Flex app to Royale it might be worthwhile considering the emulation components. setElementIndex exists there as a stub, but is waiting for a proper implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setElementIndex is not currently implemented in Royale. What we did in our app with a similar use case was to remove the element you want to move to the front and re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the following will work:

```
im2.parent.addElementAt(im2,0);
```

Have you tried it?